# JQUERY JSON response triggers parse error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to perform some basic operations with jquery json.

```
  var urlPath= encodeURIComponent('{"fields":"subject,course,unit,topic,lesson"}');
  $.ajax({

              url : 'http://abcd.org/proficiency.json?data'+urlpath,
              type : 'GET',
              dataType : 'jsonp',
              contentType: "application/json",
              success : function(data) {
              console.log("success");

              },
              error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);


   }
    });
```

The error callback is always triggers

Error... parsererror jQuery15001997238997904205_1298484897373 was not called.

How to fix it?

Thanks for reading..

Comment: Does the server actually return JSONP? Please post an example of the response.

Comment: @Aaron: Wrong. JSONP and JSON are two different things.

Comment: Wrong data type. Just remove  JSONP

Comment: Are you sure that's the right URL?

Comment: @RUJordan, url is right.

Comment: @kannan, so wat to add datatype?

Comment: why are You using contentType: "application/json" ? I think it's not needed. only dataType : 'jsonp', - will work fine. Try this.

Comment: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/11/03/ajax-datatypes-in-jquery-format-and-access/

Comment: {"content": [{"topic": [{"22920": 0.0003933333333333333},{"22937": 0.14765555555555557},{"22881": 0.0013955555555555555}]}],"message": [],"dateRange": [{}],"paginate": {}
}

Comment: @Felix Kling: server response  
{"content": [{"topic": [{"22920": 0.0003933333333333333},{"22937": 0.14765555555555557},{"22881": 0.0013955555555555555}]}],"message": [],"dateRange": [{}],"paginate": {} }

Comment: That's not JSONP, that's JSON. You cannot tell jQuery to expect JSONP if you get JSON.

Comment: @Felix Kling: i tried with dataType: json my server response is blank . when giving dataType: jsonp server response is  {"content": [{"topic": [{"22920": 0.0003933333333333333},{"22937": 0.14765555555555557},{"22881": 0.0013955555555555555}]}],"message": [],"dateRange": [{}],"paginate": {} }

Comment: @Felix Kling: i need like this then only ajax call will get success jQuery15001997238997904205_1298484897373({"content": [{"topic": [{"22920": 0.0003933333333333333},{"22937": 0.14765555555555557},{"22881": 0.0013955555555555555}]}],"message": [],"dateRange": [{}],"paginate": {} })

Comment: @Felix Kling: Its triggering the error **missing ; before statement**
 {"content": [{"topic": [{"22920": 0.0003933333333333333},{"22937": 0.14765555555555557},{"22881": 0.0013955555555555555}]}],"message": [],"dateRange": [{}],"paginate": {} }

Answer (score 0):

The server is giving back invalid JSON, there is an extra `}]` and a missing `,`. It should be changed to this:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "topic": [
                {
                    "22920": 0.0003933333333333333
                },
                {
                    "22937": 0.14765555555555557
                },
                {
                    "22881": 0.0013955555555555555
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "message": [],
    "dateRange": [
        {}
    ],
    "paginate": {}
}
```